# ESP8266 HTTPS post body request with WifiClientSecure

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, http

Is there a way to post HTTPS body request in Arduino esp8266.
I am able to HTTPS parameter request with WifiClientSecure library,but is not safe compared to Request Body send in POST.

Answer (score 1):

You do it like any other POST. It's just you happen to be using a secure client to make the connection.

1. Open the connection
2. Send the right headers, including a `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` and maybe a `Content-Encoding` if you encode it.
3. Send the body

It's not any different to an unencrypted POST request.

Comment: Can you provide me some example? or the format to include Request body with 
 a Content-Type and Content-Length and maybe a Content-Encoding as you said in point 2

Comment: Just look at any post request available on any of the millions of examples.

Comment: client.print(String("POST ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
           "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
           "Connection: close\r\n"+   
           "Content-Length: " + data.length() + "\r\n" +
           "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"+
            data +"\r\n");

data variable will contain json body?
Will this work??